# CSS help - IE misalignment

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

In Firefox/Safari/Chrome/Opera - the search bar and 4 sliders (from the page linked above) are all on 1 row.

But in IE 6/7/8, the sliders are on a new row.

Anyone know what's wrong with my CSS for IE 6/7/8 to be creating a cartridge return with the other browsers do not.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Try adding a white-space: nowrap;

Comment: @meep, where would I add "white-space: nowrap"? to the BODY tag?

Comment: It's a pure guess. Try on div#search_options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have width and padding set on the cells in the table with the sliders that make the table too wide to fit.

You have specified 270px for the width of the table, but each cell is 222px wide (150px width plus 72px padding) making the table 444px instead.

As you have specified conflicting sizes, different browsers will have different ways of dealing with it.

Comment: Thanks @Guffa, any suggestion on what I should set the widths to be. Many thanks